# how to restore elasticsearch.yml config file to original?

Tags: elasticsearch

I hosed my elasticsearch.yml with the configuration from a YouTube video, and now Elasticsearch does not start.  What is the procedure to either restore `elasticsearch.yml` to factory settings or find and edit the specific items I changed?

Comment: Can you share your yml file?

Comment: Can you share the log file portion when ES starts up?

Comment: download the elasticsearch package which is similar to the version you are using and replace the newly downloaded config file